# How to use hibernate criteria with calculation values?

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I have a hql query but I dont have any idea to convert this hql to hibernate criteria restriction. I have fountd some solutions using with @Formula Annotation.
Is there any solutions. ?

```
SELECT  SUM(dueAmount) FROM DueFromClient dfc WHERE facilityId=533 AND (dueAmount-amountReceived)>0
```

Comment: Which version of Hibernate do you use?

Comment: hibernate 3.2.7